# 889 edits, yet no Copy Editor badge

Tags: support, badges, editor

I checked the [`Users > Editor > All`](https://superuser.com/users?tab=editors&filter=all) tab, and learnt that I have made 889 edits so far. "Copy Editor" badge is given after 500 edits, but I did not receive it. What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are.. [certain requirements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/what-kind-of-edits-contribute-to-the-editor-badges) which count for "edits"

> - does not include edits to your own posts
> - does not include edits to tags
> - community-wiki posts are eligible
> - tag wiki posts are eligible
> - only edits to title and body count towards the S&W/Copy Editor badges

There is a [SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/s/511/progress-towards-editor-badges) for tracking edit progress ( thanks to [Lord Torgamus/Popular Demand for composing](https://superuser.com/users/6442/lord-torgamus?tab=accounts) the query).

The query mentions that you still need to do about ~80<sup>*****</sup> more edits to get the badge.

<sup>***** *although the query mentions you need 213 edits, the query relies on the previous requirement of 600 edits, so I shaved off 100 to get 113 edits. Considering that the SEDE relies on datadumps which are out of date and need not necessarily hold the required information, I removed 50 more edits, giving an approximate number. The actual required number might be higher/lower*</sup>

Comment: Thanks, Sathya, for your concern and help.

Comment: Wow, how odd that I would stumble across this post, since I rarely visit MSU. Please don't use my query, it doesn't work well. When it was written, the data dump didn't expose all the data needed to make an accurate query. In fact, on the day that I earned Copy Editor on MSO, my query reported that I was still __440__ edits away. Now that the badge rules have changed, I believe someone has written a superior query, though I don't know where it is.

Comment: Hm, looks like that new query is at http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1024/how-many-edits-have-i-made-and-how-much-more-until-i-earn-the-badges. I'm not sure how accurate it is, but it seems pretty close based on my check of my accounts on sites where I have edited a non-trivial number of posts.

Comment: I found yours to be more accurate. hat query told me I was 1 away from the Editor badge which I have and 80 = 500 respectively from the other two. Meaning it thinks I had made no edits... Odd... Until I realise I'm doing it completely wrong. Works fine when you do it right. Click the icon for the site you want examining. Left this comment for anyone who has the same facepalm moment I just did.